# Delete all files if another files in the same directory has a matching occurence of a specific word

Tags: shell, scripting

I have several files in a specific directory.
A specific string in one file can occur in another files.
If this string is in other files. Then all the files in which this string occured should be deleted and only 1 file should remain with the string.

Example:

```
file1
ShortName "Blue Jeans"
price 89.47
cur EURO

file2
ShortName "Blue Jeans"
Price 59.47
CUR USD

file3
ShortName "Blue Jeans"
Price 99.47
CUR GBP
```

Since the value of ShortName "Blue Jeans" is occuring in file2 & file3. Both this file should be deleted. Similarly files with other ShortName
Could any one please help me how can it done via script (ksh, SED, AWK). I am on solaris.

Comment: How do you determine which 2 of the 3 files to delete?

Comment: Also, are you going to feed the search string to the script or is it going to be looking for any string that occurs in multiple files.

Comment: 1)The condition to delete is on ShortName.
2)No feeding, the file already contains the string.The script should only look for ShortName value.
he other file should only be deleted if the ShortName value is same.
So if there are 20 files and in 15 files the string ("BlueJeans") occurs then the 14 files should be deleted and only 1 file containig the string should remain.

Comment: "then the 14 files should be deleted and only 1 file containig the string should remain." - Without regard to Price or Currency? Is there only one ShortName value per directory? **Daniel** (probably) meant are you going to feed "Blue Jeans" to the script as an argument to search for or does the script have to discover what this duplicate is? You **really** need to do a lot better job of specification.

Comment: Hello Dennis and Daniel, The specification is clear I think so. Already I wrote "No inputs", the files already contains the string.5 files can have "Blue Jeans", 4 files can contain "Yellow T shirt". If this string occurs in another file then the files in which this string occurs should be removed.And only 1 for each should remain.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`gawk` solution only for these 3 files, since no other information provided at time of writing

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR==1{ get=$0; next}
FNR!=NR && FNR==1 && $0 ~ get{ 
 cmd="rm \047"FILENAME"\047"
 print cmd
 # system(cmd) #uncomment to use 
}' 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

Comment: Hello ghostdog74
Thank you for your reply.There are n numbers of file in a directory.
Not limited to 3. How to extend your script for n file in a directory.

Thank you.

Comment: not tested, but you can try 1.txt *.txt .It should work if i am not wrong

Comment: Hello, I tried your script, some how I keep getting syntax error near line 1
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR==1 {get=$0; next} FNR!=NR && FNR==1 && $0 ~ get {cmd="rm \047"FILENAME"\047" print cmd}' file1.txt file2.txt 

I tried it from command promt & within a script file. I made sure there are no space or unwanted characters.. Can you throw some more light.

Comment: I used nwk on solaris, 
nawk 'FNR==NR && FNR==1 {get=$0; next} FNR!=NR && FNR==1 && $0 ~ get{cmd="rm \047"FILENAME""\047" print cmd}' file1.txt file2.txt nawk: syntax error at source line 1 context is FNR==NR && FNR==1 {get=$0; next} FNR!=NR && FNR==1 && $0 ~ get{cmd="rm >>> \047"FILENAME""\ <<< 047" print cmd} nawk: illegal statement at source line 1          any idea why it flash this error

Comment: what is "rm >>> " and <<< 047?? . my code don't have ">>>" !!

Comment: If I execute the script it thows error as :: 
 
nawk: syntax error at source line 1 context is FNR==NR && FNR==1 {get=$0; next} FNR!=NR && FNR==1 && $0 ~ get{cmd="rm >>> \047"FILENAME""\ <<< 047" print cmd} nawk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: Hello,
Thanks it can be executed now. The script does not iterate over all the files in the directory. 
It picks up the first file from the directory and look for the occurrence of ShortName "Blue Jeans" in remaining files. 
If another file has different ShortName " Yellow T Shirt" it does not process this.

Answer (score 0):

This script finds all duplicates and leaves only one example of each. For example, let us say there are three "Blue Jean" files, two "Plaid Shirt" files, one "Sneakers" file and several files with no "ShortName". After running this script, you should have one each: "Blue Jeans", "Plaid Shirt" and "Sneakers" and the other files should be untouched. Price and currency are completely ignored.

Paranoid disclaimer: This is ugly and guaranteed to blow up. Caveat emptor. No refunds.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="apparel"
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
strings=($(sed -n 's/ShortName "\(.*\)"/\1/p' ${dir}/*|sort|uniq -c))    # dummy comment to fix syntax coloring (ignore me) */
IFS="$saveIFS"
for string in "${strings[@]}"
do
    count=${string:0:7}
    count=${count// }
    string=${string:8}
    if [[ $count > 1 ]]
    then
        first=1
        for f in $(grep -l "$string" ${dir}/*)                           # dummy comment to fix syntax coloring (ignore me) */
        do
            if [[ $first ]]
            then
                unset first
            else
                echo rm "$f"
            fi
        done
     fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` after you've tested it to make the `rm` work.

Comment: Hello Dennis,
Yes I tested it and it is working. Under which circumstances will it blow up, what are it pitfalls. I tested it for some 30 file. But on production I am expecting more than 200 files. Can this survive ?.. your view.. please.

Comment: My confidence is somewhat improved after reading your comment clarifying the initial conditions (the comment which references "Yellow T shirt). The pitfalls: I have not tested this extensively, I don't think it will have a problem if filenames have spaces or other such characters, the search string could be more robust (in any of a number of ways - here's one: `^[ \t]*ShortName[ \t]\+"\(.*\)"[ \t]*$`), parsing the output of `uniq -c` using `${var:n:m}` might need different values for n and m on some systems, you could do `mv` into a temporary directory then check it then delete it, etc.

Comment: If it works on your 30 file test, there's no reason it shouldn't work for 200 files. As always, backups are your friend.